# Anchor link disappears after click in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using `site_url` for buttons in CodeIgniter, when you click the button a PDF downloads. it works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE when I click on the button the PDF downloads, but the button disappears. What Am I doing wrong?

here is the whole code `<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/button/pdf');?>">Download PDF</a></li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/button/pdf');?>">Download PDF</a>
```

**Quote OP**: *"in IE when I click on the button the PDF downloads, but the button disappears."*

That's not a `button`, that's an `anchor` tag, `<a></a>`.  And since PHP code is processed on the server before it gets to any browser, your problem has nothing to do with PHP or CodeIgniter.

Sound like you have a CSS issue if the link vanishes after you click it... maybe the `:visited` pseudeo-class changes the font color to something that matches your background?

Check your CSS file for rules like this.

```
 background-color: #ffffff;
```

You're looking for `background-color` on things like `body`, `ul`, `li` or whatever specific parent element contains your download link.

Then check for rules similar to this.

```
a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

where `a` is targeting your specific download link.   It's likely that the `color` value on this is matching its `background-color`.  Also, if this only happens in IE, then you may have some poorly written or invalid CSS pseudo-class selectors.